# Replace Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(....)); with List.of("....");

Tags: java

I want to migrate old Java code to Java 17. Is it a good idea to replace:

`Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(....));` to `List.of("....");`

Should I expect code execution error or there should be no impact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## specific answer

Obviously, the best way to figure this out is to try it yourself.
If you want some certainty before you attack this challenge, it is usually a good idea to look at the method signatures in the java API documentation for the different versions.

- Java 7 spec of `Collections.unmodifiableList`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)
- Java 17 spec of `List.of`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of()

As you can see, both return an unmodifiable `List<E>`. So I would say your update is quite safe.

## general approach

In general, if you are going to refactor a common part of your codebase, it is a good practice to first extract all occurrences of this construct in your codebase onto a utility method.
For your case, you could create a simple utility class, like so:

```
public final class ListUtilWrapper {
   public static <E> List<E> listOf(E... elements) {
       return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(elements));
   }
}
```

After each call is replaced by `ListUtilWrapper.listOf(....)`, you compile and test your code.
Next up, you replace the implementation of `ListUtilWrapper.listOf` to be `List.of(elements)` and rebuild your codebase.

If all works well: inline the utility method after some manual testing. If it fails, you can easily roll back to a stable state.

Comment: One important difference is that `List.of(...)` doesn't allow null elements.